# Debug Netduino without .NET Micro Framework

Tags: debugging, netduino

I have a [Netduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netduino), but I am programming it using the GNU ARM toolchain in [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) and [VisualGDB](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/arm/stm32/) so the [.NET Micro Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Micro_Framework) (NETMF) firmware has been removed. Is there a way I can set it up for debugging from Eclipse or VisualGDB?